# How to fix 'Fetch data alerting but not showing in VUE'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise, async-await

I was trying to create a common fetch method on `main.js` file that can handle the response data and response code and Also can catch the error(return response error) and show error code.

For example:-
If the response code is `500` show an error popup.
If the response code is `401` the go to login page
If the response code is `409` show an error popup etc..

So instead of writing the fetch and the conditions i created a common method and i passed the URL as parameter to it.

But i encountered an issue that is i did't get any response from the fuction call to the variable.

The fetch code was like this in `fee.js`

```
fetch('/api/fee/' + id, {
                method: 'GET',
                credentials: 'include',

}).then(response => {
        if (response.status == 200) {
            this.get_fee_list = json.data.fee
        }
        else if (response.status == 401) {
            window.location.replace("/login");
        }
        else if (response.status == 409) {
            this.notAuthorisedModal: true
        }
        else{
            this.showModal: true
        }
})
.catch(error => {
    showErrorModal: true
})
```

Then i change it into a function like bellow in `main.js`

```
function fetchData(url){

    fetch(url + id, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    credentials: 'include',

    }).then(response => {
            if (response.status == 200) {
                return json.data.fee
            }
            else if (response.status == 401) {
                window.location.replace("/login");
            }
            else if (response.status == 409) {
                this.notAuthorisedModal: true
            }
            else{
                this.showModal: true
            }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.showErrorModal: true
    })
}
```

In `fee.js` file

```
this.get_fee_list = fetchData('/api/fee/')
```

But the when i alert `get_fee_list` it shows undefined.

I tried this with `async` and `await` but then i can only write the second `then` in the callback function in `main.js`

```
async function commonApiCall(url) {
    return await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
}
```

In `fee.js`

```
data = commonApiCall('/api/fee_discount/')

data.then(function(json){
this.get_fee_list = json.data.fee;
for (const key in this.get_fee_list) {
    const element = this.get_fee_list[key];
    element["dataDisabled"] = true
}
this.$forceUpdate()
});
```

In vue devtools i found `get_fee_list` is empty array

Comment: `if (response.status == 200) { ... } else if (response.status == 200){ ... }`  that `else if` will never trigger because its condition is the same as the first

Comment: Also, `showModal: true`, `notAuthorisedModal: true` and `showErrorModal: true` are not valid JavaScript expressions

Comment: i think for 'fetch' you need to convert the promise to json, .then((response) => response.json(), there are two then for fetch method. Refer docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `window.location.href` is **not** a function

Comment: Does `/api/fee_discount` return JSON? If so, is it an object with `data` property, eg `{"data": { "fee": [...] } }`

Comment: @Phil Thank you for your comments.    Yes the respone in `{"data": { "fee": [...] } }`.